# Is it right to create one instance of an object and share it between all the methods of that class?

Tags: java, spring, variables, scope, global-variables

This is a small sample of my service class which contains seversal methods and instead of creating several instances of the TerminalEntity for an example , i have put it at the top.

```
  private final TerminalRepository terminalRepository;
  List<Terminal> terminalsList = new ArrayList<>();
  Terminal terminalResponseModel = new Terminal();
  TerminalEntity terminalEntity  = new TerminalEntity();
  
  public ResponseEntity<Terminal> addTerminal(Terminal terminal) {
    log.info("Adding New Terminal Object..." + terminal);

    ObjectMapperUtils.map(terminal, terminalEntity);

    terminalEntity.setTerminalId(UUID.randomUUID());
    terminalEntity.setMerchantId(terminal.getMerchantId());
    terminalEntity.setOutletId(terminal.getOutletId());

    terminalRepository.save(terminalEntity);
    log.info("Saved Terminal Entity : {}", terminalEntity);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(terminal, HttpStatus.CREATED);
  }

  public ResponseEntity<Object> getTerminalsByDeviceID(String deviceId) {

    if (!UUIDValidator.isValidUUID(deviceId)) {
      throw new BadRequestException(Constants.INVALID_UUID_MESSAGE);
    }

     terminalEntity = terminalRepository.findTerminalByDeviceId(deviceId);
    return mapAndGetTerminalResponseModel(terminalEntity);
  }
This will cause any kind of problems or this is a good practice ?
```

Comment: Post your question here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Generally speaking, the **whole point** of member variables is that you have an object that is shared between all methods. Whether this makes sense or not depends on the nature of the object, and in the relationship of the 'maybe shared' object to the intended function of the class.  Consider this: a String has a sequence of characters that is shared between all String methods; it would be insane if each method somehow needed its own sequence of characters.  A good rule of thumb is to use the smallest scope that works. This is a matter of correct design, not a coding issue.